# Azure Release pipeline failures(CICD) for ADF pipelines having scope activities inside them

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

we are using scope activity in ADF and also enabled ADFScopeSupport as true but when we are doing Publishing via release pipelines to another Datafactory, it failed stating reason as client Ip not authorized. I used remote desktop also for publishing but again getting the same failure. Can anyone help how to enable CICD process for pipelines having scope activities. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you set the **ADFScopeSupport** flag as it locks you out of your Factory.

You should set ADFScopeSupport to false and try again.

There is also a troubleshooting guide available which you can follow:

Go to the Azure DevOps, Supportability repo.

**Supportability -> AzureDataFactory -> Overview -> Wiki**

Then search for `Scope Activity: Restricting Authoring`

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, if I set "ADFScopeSupport" to false then ADF is throwing validation error for the pipelines having scope Activity. So "ADFScopeSupport" needs to be true before doing CICD operation. Thanks